# Converting optional Binding to non-optional Binding

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want extend Binding extension with a func that we can convert an optional Binding to a non-optional Binding and use it as a normal Binding. I almost could finish it but xCode through an error which I cannot handle it, I think I done everything correct.

```
extension Binding {
    
    mutating func safeBinding<T>(defaultValue: T) -> Binding<T> where Value == Optional<T> {
        
        let safeValue: T
        
        if let unwrappedValue: T = self.wrappedValue { safeValue = unwrappedValue }
        else { safeValue = defaultValue }

        return Binding.init(get: { () -> T in return safeValue },
                            set: { (newValue) in self.wrappedValue = newValue })
 
        
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Binding<Optional<T>>' to return type 'Binding<T>'
```

### Updated code for my way:

```
extension Binding {
    
     func safeBinding<T>(defaultValue: T) -> Binding<T> where Value == Optional<T> {
        
        let safeValue: T
        
        if let unwrappedValue: T = self.wrappedValue { safeValue = unwrappedValue }
        else { safeValue = defaultValue }

        return SwiftUI.Binding.init(get: { () -> T in return safeValue },
                                    set: { (newValue) in self.wrappedValue = newValue })
 
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Binding` has an associated type `Value` already, so by trying to use `T`, you're putting a new generic on top of `Value`, which already exists.

But, you will still end up using `T` because you'll want to constrain `Value` to scenarios where it is Optional:

```
extension Binding {
    func safeBinding<T>(defaultValue: T) -> Binding<T> where Value == Optional<T> {
        .init {
            self.wrappedValue ?? defaultValue
        } set: { newValue in
            self.wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

---

As noted in the comments, the Xcode compiler has difficulty if just `Binding.init` is used (note that I used just `.init`). This can be solved by explicitly using `Binding<T>.init`:

```
extension Binding {
    func safeBinding<T>(defaultValue: T) -> Binding<T> where Value == Optional<T> {
        Binding<T>.init {
            self.wrappedValue ?? defaultValue
        } set: { newValue in
            self.wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you are using `.init` if we use Binding in front of it like `Binding.init`, it would not work! why? are we not using a Binding init?

Comment: You just have to be more explicit with the typing and use `Binding<T>.init` -- the compiler should probably be able to infer that, but for some reason, it doesn't.

Comment: I wrote my answer before you edited your question to use `Value == Optional<T>` (which explains my first sentence), but yes, it looks like after that, it's just simplification of the code. Like I said, using `Binding<T>.init` works.

Comment: we must use `SwiftUI.Binding.init` So with that said how can I refactor my original code!?

Comment: I find it out! I make an update to codes! I should use `SwiftUI.Binding.init` explicitly and also omit  mutating. :)

Comment: The problem here is that `Binding.init` infers `Optional<T>` as type. Now I think that this is a bug since it should infer `T` as a type (both by the return type as well as the function signature for `get`). I think that this has something to do with the signature for `set` but I'm not sure.

Comment: This should just be an overload for `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/init(projectedvalue:)`.